# How will I know if something is wrong with the engine due to the radiator

Tags: bmw

I want to buy this car from a friend but the radiator is broke and someone told me that the engine could have been damaged so how would I know if the engine is ok?

Comment: Define broke? A slow leak is definitely broke, but a manageable broke. Catastrophic failure on the other hand often leads to a warped head on the BMW engines.

Answer (score 4):

The BMW's engine could be damaged due to overheating if the radiator is defective. If you are unsure of the mechanical condition of a vehicle you intend to purchase the answer is simple. Don't buy it. Engine repairs on BMW's would be quite pricey. It would probably be cheaper to buy a used or new car from a reputable dealer. You would be protected from defects by applicable consumer protection laws in your country. If you intend to still purchase the vehicle from your friend your friend should have the vehicle repaired and inspected prior to offering it for sale. Otherwise you could be stuck with a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

Open the water reservoir cap and check for green sludge under the cap or oil in the water, if the engine is damaged you will find out this way(headgasket is burnt). Much worse damages are very easy to see, just check the exhaust and look for blue gas.

You may also check the vehicle with a BMW dealer to check it for faults and warnings.BMW logs warnings and faults in its memory and if the engine is overheated there must be some warning and errors upthere for example "Engine is too hot, drive moderatly" Doing this you may find other expensive faults like oil pressure in transmission, water pump RPM and ..... which could cost more than a burnt head gasket.

However, I bet the engine is damaged since most of BMWs do not have an engine temperature gauge, and the driver will not find out any problem till it is too late.